# Bar / Column Charts with values

Tags: qgis

I'm quite new to QGIS, but with QGIS 2.18.3 64 Bit @ Windows 7, I managed to set up a European map with a bar chart overlay.
However, it doesn't look neither very nice nor professional, as there are some charts overlaying each other and, what's worse, overlaying the country shortname, please see screenshot attached.

Moreover, I want to add the values to the created bars - is there a way how I can do it?
If that's not possible with the built-in methods, is there any plugin you can recommend for doing so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the **D3 Render Plugin**, which is [documented here](http://maprenderer.org/d3/). I haven't used it much, but it looks promising.

This creates an interactive web page, where clicking on a feature will show a bar graph in a popup window (very simple example below). This has the advantage of not cluttering up your map with bar charts.

[image]

It also has a lot of options for projections (some of which QGIS/GDAL don't support!) and has a lot more types of diagram than are available with the standard QGIS Drawing functions.

The output is a javascript web application; if you have JavaScript skills, you can modify this quite easily to get the look you want. (Although numbers aren't added to the bars, that could be done in Javascript)

Comment: The first thing I noticed, you lost Serbia and Bosnia and Herzegovina. If you new with qgis,  first you have to  learn.  Your large bars can divide with 10, 100, or 1000 or wathever to minimize bar.    You can learn from a professional, Toto Fiandaca,  to this video https://youtu.be/vDcyGNqsuSI