# Making bar charts with values in popup windows in web map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, chart, d3

I'm an amateur of QGIS.

I've set up a map with a bar chart overlay. However, there are some charts overlaying each other. So I would like to create a map which when people click / however an area on the map, a pop-up window will then show the bar charts.

Something similar to [this](http://luminocity3d.org/WorldCity/#3/12.00/10.00).

I tried D3 Render Plugin as informed by [Bar / Column Charts with values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227245) and follow the [d3 MapRenderer](http://maprenderer.org/d3/) guide.

However, I cannot select the field that I would like to visualize in the bar chart.

Any advice what to do?

[image]

Comment: i am wondering about the same issue, I don't know which methodology would be the best to implement your issue. I know that there is a soulution with R and the leaflet package. You might check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57087065/how-to-show-multiple-texts-on-pop-up-in-leaflet-map-in-r